# Idiomatic pattern for subtracting a function from a list

Tags: functional-style, idiomatic-usage

I would like to know a more idiomatic way to subtract a function from a list of pairs than this:

```
Table[point-{0,fitFunction[point[[1]]]}, {point,data}]
```

I use this when I subtract signals from data. `data` is list of pairs of numbers and `fitFunction` is a function from using `NonlinearModelFit` on a portion of the `data`. For instance, here I fit a Cauchy distribution to the large trough using `NonlinearModelFit` then subtract the model from the data in order to see the smaller troughs in the absence of the fitted one:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try this: `oc = data;     oc[[All, 2]] -= fitFunction /@ data[[All, 1]];`

Comment: @Kuba Thanks! I was worried about posting such a simple question but I never would have come up with anything like that myself...

Comment: Are you looking for the fit residuals? For instance, If your `FittedModel` object is saved in the variable `nlm = NonlinearModelFit[...]; nlm["FitResiduals"]`. If you want the lists of pairs of fit residuals as a function of the original independent variable, then `Transpose@{nlm["Data"][[All, 1]], nlm["FitResiduals"]}`.

Comment: @MarcoB Not quite, unless there is more functionality there than I understand. I'm fitting only the largest peak (the fitted points are blue) and then subtracting that function from the data (orange) in the second plot.

Comment: @Diffycue Yeah so then the smaller peaks would be the "residuals", i.e. the "unfitted parts" of the original data, no? I.e. the difference between the predicted response (i.e. the largest peak) and the actual response). Give it a try, then let me know if it works.

Comment: @MarcoB I'll try it, but I anticipate a problem since I don't want to fit the whole range of data to the model but only the subset marked in blue in the first plot.

Comment: @MarcoB, indeed, since the fit is to fewer points than the data set as a whole there is a problem using `nlm["FitResiduals"]` as the y-axis data if I want the x-axis to range to the right of the fitted points. Maybe `NonlinearModelFit` has functionality for fitting subranges that I don't know about? If that were the case then your suggestion would be perfect, but I can't find it in the documentation.